# How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed and delete those lines

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

Suppose a file contains:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
mno
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
pqr
stu
mno
```

And the starting pattern is abc and ending pattern is mno So, I need the output as:

```
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

i.e anything between abc and mno should be removed and I want anything after abc including abc if it's not ended by mno to be printed

I tried this `sed '/^abc$/,/^mno$/{//!b};d' file` but it delete all lines except for those between lines starting `abc` and `mno`.

Comment: is the fifth line in sample a mistake? if so, a simple `sed '/^abc$/,/^mno$/d' file` will work.. if not, explain why `abc` is not in output

Comment: @Sundeep, Sir if you wouldn't mind May I tell you what I think is, output is coming as `def2
ghi2
jkl2` since just before `def2` an occurrence of `abc` is there which is NOT closed and again a following `abc` is coming after it,IMHO that is why OP wants to print it, but OP only could confirm this.

Comment: Re "*anything between abc and mno should be removed*", The lines you asked to keep are between `abc` and `mno`...

Comment: No 5th line is not mistake . I want anything after abc including abc if it's not ended by mno .

Comment: @AnupamDas, eaxclty that's what I tried to explain above. Please change your question and make it more clear.

Comment: @ikegami no I want lines between abc and mno to be removed

Comment: `def2`, `ghi2` and `jkl2` are between `abc` and `mno`, but you said you wanted to keep them

Comment: @ikegami, IMHO, what OP is saying its a cycle(from `abc` to `mno`) in case any `abc` is followed by another `abc` and `mon` in that cycle is missing then at that time those elements which are coming from 2 `abc`s should be printed.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, That is the same view I'm taking. There are two cycles, and the encompass the entirety of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the input on `abc\n` you might get away with removing those that contain `mno`, e.g. with GNU awk:

```
awk '!/mno/' RS='abc\n' infile
```

```
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

Comment: This is a GNU awk extension. In POSIX awk, the variable `RS` can only be a single character.

Comment: This will fail if `mno` appears before the first `abc`

Comment: @kvantour: I explicitly mentioned GNU awk and this works with the example provided by the OP, although it is unclear what he really wants

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/abc/{:a;x;z;x;:b;n;/abc/{:c;g;s/.//p;ba};/mno/d;H;$bc;bb};p' file
```

Any lines before or after a cycle of `abc` thru `mno` will be printed as normal. Any lines between a cycle of `abc` and a following `abc` will printed less the first and last lines of the cycle. All other lines will be deleted i.e. a cycle between `abc` and `mno` with no `abc` lines between. For the special case of a cycle `abc` and the end of the file with no `abc` or `mno` lines between, all lines except the first will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it that works with any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{begpat="^abc$"; endpat="^mno$" }
     ($0 ~ endpat) { n=0; buffer=""; next }
     ($0 ~ begpat) { n=1; if(buffer) print buffer; buffer=""; next }
     (n==0) { print; next }
     {buffer = (buffer ? buffer ORS : "") $0 }
     END { if(buffer) print buffer }' file
```

The following logictable explains how this works:

```
   from\to | begpat | endpat | END        BEGIN: BEGIN OF FILE
   --------+--------+--------+-----       END  : END OF FILE
    BEGIN  |   1    |   1    |  1
   --------+--------+--------+-----       1: print lines between [from,to]
    begpat |   1    |   0    |  1         0: don't print lines between [from,to]
   --------+--------+--------+-----
    endpat |   1    |   1    |  1
```

The above shows that there is only an exception when `begpat` is met. Only in this case we build a buffer to decide if we have to print.